# AIC / BIC for Model Selection in Copula Model

Tags: model-selection, likelihood, aic, copula, bic

I'm trying to select the distributional model of 30 marginals (which are restricted to have the same distributional family) in a copula model. However, I therefore get 30 Likelihood/AIC/BIC values for each model family. Is there any "correct" way to "summarize" the 30 Values in to 1 comparable number? I.e. Summing up the likelihoods and use this to compute a new AIC/BIC value or take some kind of average etc...

Comment: https://tnagler.github.io/VineCopula/reference/BiCopVuongClarke.html